# How to create custom User Group programmatically in Joomla 3.x?

Tags: joomla, components, joomla3.0, joomla-component

I am writing a custom Component in Joomla 3.x.

At a certain point of the component I need to create a Custom User Group under 'Registered' group in Joomla.

After searching the web a lot, I found no solution of this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add it to the `#__usergroups` table programmatically, ensuring the user group is not there already; or get an instance of `JTableUsergroup` (declared in `libraries/joomla/table/usergroup.php`). Since it extends `JTable` you can use its `save()` method, passing an array with the values you wish to store.

Then in order to have proper lft and rgt values, you need to invoke the `rebuild()` method on `JTableUsergroup`.

Please ensure adding it programmatically is really necessary, it may cause issues on sites that already make heavy use of usergroups.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this without manually add rows in the table and invoke rebuild() function?

Comment: I improved the answer to explain how

Comment: It will automatically do the rebuild() on store().