# Is there a Joomla (3.x) development API for creating and managing custom user groups?

Tags: joomla

I just started with Joomla 3.x and I'm writing a component for Joomla v3 which is supposed to create new usergroups for creating 'groups'- the design requirements being:

1. An organisation may set up a group to offer access to some set of services -including communication but also also other types of services - to their members
   (the other services is the reason why I believe the community and forum joomla extensions are not suitable- they mostly focus at fora and social media services, not the services I will implement.)
2. Other persons/members of the organisation may register to this group, which allow him/her to access these services

ps: it is also possible for person to set up a personal account and get access to the set of services. This person may also join one or more groups at a later stage

How to do code the creating of new usergroups? I noticed a possible suggested solution at [How to create custom User Group Programmatically in Joomla 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544681/how-to-create-custom-user-group-programmatically-in-joomla-3-x), but I struggle to understand how to use the suggested JTableUsergroup class because of the limited documentation at http://docs.joomla.org/API17:JTableUsergroup(?) Does creating an instance of JTableUsergroup results in the creation of a new customer user group?

Another question: how to add users to a customer usergroup? The only hint I found was at http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JUserHelper.html - using the method addUserToGroup of class JUserHelper.

Many of the Joomla development concepts are well document but I could not find one for managing custom user groups...

Appreciate your help;-)

Answer (score 0):

First, overall, the best consistent documentation of Joomla APIs is in the docblocks for the classes. Then to be honest what I do a lot of times is to search for where in the core the API is used. There are some great pieces of narrative documentation in the wiki, but on the whole I always start with the docblocks which are very complete.  However in this case it's pretty simple.

You need to do something along the lines of

```
$newrow = JTable::getInstance('Usergroup');
//code to add your data

$newtable->save(); // Shortcut for check, bind, store
```

However, if I were you I would look carefully at `UsersModelGroup` because there are a lot of other things that should normally happen in this process such as running the user plugins. So I might include and extend that model (which manages the table class) rather than going to the table class directly.  In fact your whole component might even be able to extend almost all of the users component or it might also be possible that you could do what you want with plugins rather than reinventing the whole thing.

In terms of assigning users to groups that is trickier because of some legacy things in the code.  I think the setter followed by a `$user->save()`  ($user being a JUser instance) is probably the way to go when adding to groups.  What I probably would do is to write a custom `JFormField` that would manage opt-in groups because the core usergroup field includes everything. You could extend that and exclude the groups that you want to have only managed by admin.

Comment: thnx for the suggestions, Elin